# WSO2 Micro Integrator throws an error when content type is application/ld+json

Tags: wso2, json-ld, wso2-integration-studio

I want to call an API that I created with Integration Studio. There are headers that this API uses. API returns ld+json data.When I make a request to the API I created via Postman,gives the following error.

```
Unexpected character in preface '{' (code 123); expected '<' in [row,col
```

I added TRANSPORT_HEADERS as remove using Property Mediator. But this time, the API does not work because the Headers information is deleted. I added the following lines to the deployment.toml and axis2.xml files. But it still didn't work.

```
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "application/json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
```

Below is the xml file I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/x" name="x" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var x = mc.getPayloadJSON();

if    (x.id == "urn:ngsi-ld:AirQualitySensor:012")
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"success"}');
else 
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"fail"}');]]></script>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Seems like the theres an issue identifying the content type of the request. 
Within Postman, check the request's content type of the Body. Set it to `raw` and from the dropdown next to it, select JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the correct custom content type to the appropriate `message builder`. For example if your response content type is `application/ld+json` you need to add the message builder like the below.

```yaml
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "application/ld+json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
```